# Relation between eigenvalues and matrix's characteristic

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

If I let $A$ be a $4×4$ real matrix with eigenvalues $−1, 1, 2, 3$ I am having hard time figuring out matrix characteristic!

1. Is matrix A invertible? (I think it is invertible since it has no $0$ eigenvalues)
2. Is A diagonalizable?(I am not sure but I think it is diagonalizable since all four eigenvalues are different. )
3. Is there a basis, for $\mathbb{R}^4$ consisting of eigenvectors of
   $A$? (I could not understand this question )
4. Find the determinant of $AA^{t}$ (I think it is $36$)
5. Find the trace of $(A^2 − 3I)−1$ (Is it $1/6$ right?)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 3. and 2. are the same. The rest is all right

Comment: @Exodd Do you  mean the matrix A is diagonalizable and there exist a basis for R4 consisting of eigenvectors of A ?

Comment: @chaeyeon see my answer

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if the eigen vectors of $A$ form a basis of $\mathbb{F}^{n}$.

In that suppose the matrix is of dimension $n$.

You take the matrix $P$ whose columns are those $n$ eigen vectors.

Then $P^{-1}AP=diag(\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},...\lambda_{n})$ where $\lambda_{i}$'s are not necessarily distinct.

Now since the matrix has $4$ eigen values and eigen vectors corresponding to different eigen values are linearly independent so you have a set of $4$ linearly independent eigen vectors which is a basis as $\dim(\mathbb{R}^{4})=4$ . Write these 4 eigen vectors as the columns of $P$ to get the required transformation wrt which you get the diagonal matrix.

Also for the last part see that $Ax=\lambda x\implies A^{2}x=\lambda Ax=\lambda^{2}x$ . So $A^{2}$ has eigen values which are the squares of eigen values of $A$. And sum of eigen values is the trace of matrix.
So $Tr(A^{2}-3I)=1+1+4+9-(3+3+3+3)=15-12=3$.

Comment: "A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has a basis of eigen vectors." could be better phrased - as stated it appears to talk about bases for a matrix...

Comment: You're right. I'll change it

Comment: This version is _wrong_. If $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ then the column space of $A$ has a basis consisting of eigenvectors but $A$ is not diagonalizable.  What's true is that an $n\times n$ matrix over the field $\Bbb F$ is diagonalizable if and only if $\Bbb F^n$ has a basis consiting of eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Oh no!!!. I completely miswrote that . I got confused sorry . I'll edit it .

Comment: English: Saying the eigenvectors "form" a basis means that the set of all eigenvectors is a basis; that's impossible unless there are no eigenvectors. (There's a correct statement of the condition somewhere in this thread...)